# Transfer control to new window - chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, multi-window

How to transfer control to new window?
Im working on a chrome packaged app with multi-window functionality. Suppose i click on "new window" and it opens up a new window this is the code im using:

background.js:

```
function create_window(opt_options)
{
    chrome.app.window.create("main.html", opt_options,

    });
}
```

Right after creating a new window im simply populating the value in the div

main.html

```
<html class="full-height">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="username">Guest</div>
```

In main.html there a button that called the function for new function from background.js and add username in the div:

main.js

```
$(".menu-new-window").click(function() {

    create_window()

    $("user_name").html("John Doe");
});
```

The basic flow is, i select a user "John" from the list (parent/first window), a new window will open and John will be populated in the head section (div id username) of the new window. But after opening a new window it adds John in the parent window instead of new window. This happens whenever i open a new window, it always update its parent window.

I've just started developing the app so there's not much code to display, i've displayed some basic code of how im trying to work with multi-windows.

Please let me know if my question is not clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: Javascript is executed in the context of a window. Just use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to pass the values to the new window's script. To provide a more detailed answer or to link to a duplicate question I think we need more specifics from you.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to show more code for this to be answerable - how do you try to change things?

Comment: @wOxxOm It may be easier to use `contentWindow` in this particular case, but we need to see more code.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for you reply. Please check now i've updated the post with some code. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wOxxOm mentions, when you execute code within a document, that affects that document. Even just theoretically, *how* would your particular code know which window you mean?

There are probably 4 broad methods you can use, and I'm not saying they are exhaustive. I also won't go into too much detail.

1. Open a window with some parameters encoded in the URL

   You can use either query parameters or the URL fragment to pass a (small) amount of data to the new window. E.g.:

   ```
   chrome.app.window.create("main.html#u=" + encodeURIComponent("John Doe"));
   ```

   and then decode `location.hash` in the other window when it opens.

   The problem with that is: you can't pass much information this way.
2. Use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging). `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` can be used to broadcast some data to all parts of the app. The problem with it, though, is to determine which part of the app should listen.
3. Use `chrome.storage`. This is a shared storage that your original window can write to before calling a new window, and the new window can read from it. There is again some problem with identifying windows, but it's easier to avoid.
4. A direct way to access the new window is available if you do it from the callback of window creation.

   Namely, [the `contentWindow` property of `AppWindow`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#property-AppWindow-contentWindow).

   ```
   chrome.app.window.create(
     "main.html",
     opt_options,
     function(appWin) {
       otherWindow = appWin.contentWindow;
       otherWindow.username = "John Doe";
     }
   );

   // And in the other window
   window.onload = function() {
     // You can use `username` here
   }
   ```

   It's even given [as a sample in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#property-create-callback).